# inet_ntop provides different returns for the same ipv6 address on different platforms

Tags: ipv6, inet-ntop

On my Mac, inet_ntop produces this IPv6 address for a certain 128-bit value:

```
2001::53aa:64c:422:2ece:a29c:9cf6.51391
```

On my FC15 Linux system, I get this IPv6 address presentation:

```
2001:0:53aa:64c:422:2ece:a29c:9cf6.51391
```

My understanding is that zeros between :: can be ignored, so I think that these are the same address. Are they the same address? If so, why do the different operating systems display it differently?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are the same address. The :: means 'all zeroes', the other notation shows the zero.

Comment: Thanks. So why do Linux and MacOS produce different values?

Comment: Both are the same value, just written differently. Both are valid, though the Linux notation is te recommended one (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5952#section-4.2.2)